# jQuery Draggable Full Screen Image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using jQuery Draggable with an image larger than the screen (3000x3000).

To prevent the image from being dragged off the screen, i'm watching the image position

```
#screen {
    cursor: grab;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<div id="screen">
    <img src="images/big-image.jpg" class="drag-image" id="draggable" />
</div>

$("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {

        if (ui.position.top > 1032) {
            ui.position.top = 1032;
        } else if (ui.position.top < -1030) {
            ui.position.top = -1030;
        }

        if (ui.position.left > 540) {
            ui.position.left = 540;
        } else if (ui.position.left < -540) {
            ui.position.left = -540;
        }

    }
});
```

How can I prevent the image from being dragged off the screen without having to hardcode the position values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from this post [jQuery offset of element in relation to viewport](https://coderwall.com/p/a2spaq/jquery-offset-of-element-in-relation-to-viewport) I solved this by getting the image offsets and then using them to prevent the image from dragging offscreen:

```
var offset = $('#screen img').offset();
var xPos = offset.left - $(document).scrollLeft()
var yPos = offset.top - $(document).scrollTop()

$("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {

        if (ui.position.top > Math.abs(yPos)) {
            ui.position.top = Math.abs(yPos);
        } else if (ui.position.top < yPos) {
            ui.position.top = yPos;
        }

        if (ui.position.left > Math.abs(xPos)) {
            ui.position.left = Math.abs(xPos);
        } else if (ui.position.left < xPos) {
            ui.position.left = xPos;
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres *containment* options in draggable jquery-ui https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment.

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region.

Which accepts

- 'parent'
- 'document'
- 'window'
- jquery selector

`>$("#draggable").draggable({
 containment: 'window'
});`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that the image is larger than the browser window. Dragging the image first snaps to the top, upper left (-1094px, -692px) and then more dragging reorients the image off the screen.